# What's the value of concurrency for sagas?

Tags: nservicebus, masstransit

I do not get the purpose of concurrent messages for saga. I'd expect it to behave more like an actor. So all the messages with the same `CorrelationId` are processed sequentially. The whole purpose of saga is orchestration of a **long** running process, so why does parallel message processing matter?

Can you give a legit example where handling messages concurrently for the saga instance is beneficial compared to the sequential mode?

Or do I understand it wrong, and concurrency just means several different saga instances running in parallel?

The reason to ask is this fragment from NServiceBus [docs](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/sagas/#accessing-databases-and-other-resources-from-a-saga):

> The main reason for avoiding accessing data from external resources is possible contention and inconsistency of saga state. Depending on persister, the saga state is retrieved and persisted with either pessimistic or optimistic locking. **If the transaction takes too long, it's possible another message will come in that correlates to the same saga instance.** It might be processed on a different (concurrent) thread (or perhaps a scaled out endpoint) and it will either fail immediately (pessimistic locking) or while trying to persist the state (optimistic locking). In both cases the message will be retried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's none, messages for the single saga instance need to be processed sequentially. There's nothing special about saga configuration in MassTransit, you really want to use a separate endpoint for it and set the concurrency limit to one.

But that would kill the performance for processing messages for different saga instances. To solve this, keep the concurrently limit higher than one and use the partitioning filter by correlation id. Unfortunately, the partitioning filter requires by-message configuration, so you'd need to configure the partitioning for all messages that the saga consumes.

But it all depends on the use-case. All the concurrency issues are resolved by retries when using the persistence-based optimistic concurrency, which is documented per saga persistence provider. Certainly, it produces some noise by retrying database operations, but if the number of retries is under control, you can just keep it as it is.

If you hit tons of retries due to massive concurrent updates, you can revert to partitioning your saga.

Comment: Ok, I got the point. In principle, it is possible to have multiple machines processing sagas, so there is a concurrency anyway.

Comment: Correct, there is concurrency _across_ saga instances, but not within the same instance. MassTransit (or NSB I presume) serializes messages to the same saga instance by correlationId. If optimistic concurrency is used, an instance may be loaded and run from two separate messages (with one of them discarded when the database update is rejected) so keep that in mind when selecting a persistence mechanism.

Comment: Avoiding concurrency across different instances would require coordination, which brings a lot of complexity. Whilst it is possible to implement in theory, the practical resolution is often just to let it go and use optimistic concurrency, forcing the instance to retry.

Comment: I'd also add that with MT 7 and Riders, it should be possible to use some more advanced brokers, like Pulsar and their capabilities for pinned consumers. Maybe RMQ routing key could work similarly.